# Question on linearly independence of two functions.

Tags: derivatives, determinant

Given two differentiable functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ defined on $(0, 1].$ Suppose their Wronskian only at $t=1$ is non-zero and at other values of $t\in (0, 1)$ is zero, i.e $\begin{vmatrix}
f(t) \quad g(t)\\
f'(t)\quad g'(t)\end{vmatrix}_{t=1}\neq 0, $ then can I conclude that these are linearly independent on $(0, 1]?$  My major doubt here is what is the meaning of $f'(1)$ and $g'(1)$ and how do we calculate these values, as we know the derivatives at the end points of an interval is undefined.

Comment: The Wronskian needs to be nonzero everywhere. A derivative at an endpoint may correspond here to a left derivative (i.e., limits from the left).

Comment: But I studied if the Wronskian is non-zero even at at least one point in an interval, then on the whole interval those functions are LI.

Answer (score 0):

If the wronskian is 0 in (0,1) then there exist constants a and b, not both 0, such that af+bg=0. By continuity the equation holds at 1 also. If we assume that f anf g have a left-hand derivative at 1 it follows that wronskian is necessarily 0 at 1 also.

Comment: If Wronskian at 1 is non-zero, and nothing is known about the Wronskian at other values of t, then what can we say about f and g on (0, 1]?

Answer (score 0):

If the derivatives f and g are continuous at 1 and the Wronskian is nonzero at 1, then it is nonzero on an interval containing 1. Then f and g are linearly independent on this smaller interval, hence on the whole interval from 0 to 1.

Comment: How do we calculate the derivatives at 1?

Comment: Using left-hand limits.

Comment: So you mean $f'(1)=$left hand derivative of $f(\cdot)$ at $t=1?$ And similarly for $g(\cdot)?$